# Data Aggregation of CSV files java

Tags: java, database, hashing, big-data, aggregate

I have `k` csv files (5 csv files for example), each file has `m` fields which produce a key and `n` values. I need to produce a single csv file with aggregated data.

I'm looking for the most efficient solution for this problem, speed mainly. I don't think by the way that we will have memory issues. Also I would like to know if hashing is really a good solution because we will have to use 64 bit hashing solution to reduce the chance for a collision to less than 1% (we are having around 30000000 rows per aggregation).

For example

```
file 1: f1,f2,f3,v1,v2,v3,v4
        a1,b1,c1,50,60,70,80
        a3,b2,c4,60,60,80,90 

file 2: f1,f2,f3,v1,v2,v3,v4
        a1,b1,c1,30,50,90,40
        a3,b2,c4,30,70,50,90

result: f1,f2,f3,v1,v2,v3,v4  
        a1,b1,c1,80,110,160,120
        a3,b2,c4,90,130,130,180
```

algorithm that we thought until now:

1. hashing (using concurentHashTable)
2. merge sorting the files
3. DB: using mysql or hadoop or redis.

The solution needs to be able to handle Huge amount of data (each file more than two million rows)

a better example: file 1

```
country,city,peopleNum
england,london,1000000
england,coventry,500000
```

file 2:

```
country,city,peopleNum
england,london,500000
england,coventry,500000
england,manchester,500000
```

merged file:

```
country,city,peopleNum
england,london,1500000
england,coventry,1000000
england,manchester,500000
```

The key is: `country,city`. This is just an example, my real key is of size 6 and the data columns are of size 8 - total of 14 columns.

We would like that the solution will be the fastest in regard of data processing.

Comment: Is this line number based? Should line 10 from file1 be aggregated with line 10 from file2?

Comment: for hashing, see [Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/49550/31260)

Comment: How many rows are we talking? Will it be practical to hold all the keys in memory at once? (What real performance requirements are we talking; would batch processing be adequate?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the key-fileds are always the first colums i would sort the source rows (whithout the header) by the keys and then advance in both files line  by line similar to [Merge_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) used in [Mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort).

But instead of sorting the 2 csv-lists to one you compute the sum of elements that are in both list. Elements that are in one list only are simply copied.

The algorithm looks similar to this:

```
While (NOT EndOfFile(left-item) AND NOT EndOfFile(right-item))
  if (EndOfFile(right-item) OR left-item.key < right-item.key) store(left-item); advance left-item;
  if (EndOfFile(left-item) OR left-item.key > right-item.key) store(right-item); advance right-item;
  if (left-item.key = right-item.key) store(sum(right-item, left-item)); advance right-item; advance left-item
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database to store the results (and handle the transactions) and then just write a small script which reads a file and inserts and/or updates the data accordingly (line per line).
You can then run the script in parallel on all your input files and fork off as much as your machine can take, or even run it on multiple machines.

The database will be the bottleneck, though.

Comment: Not sure this will scale.  With hundreds of millions of rows per file this seems a better use case for breaking the files into smaller subsets and using map-reduce to make processing highly parallel.  Hadoop would be a better solution.